# How can I provide different fulfillment URLs for Actions on Google Release?

Tags: url, actions-on-google, fulfillment

The documentation at https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments states "To handle release channels in your fulfillment, you should provide different fulfillment URLs (for example, one fulfillment URL for the beta and another URL for the production version of your Action)." However, there are no instructions on how this should be accomplished.

When I created my Actions on Google project, a Firebase project was created to which I upload JavaScript that supports those actions via requests to our backend service. That Firebase project provides the URL used by my Beta release for fulfillment. I now need to create an Alpha project that points to a different Firebase project to which I will upload new versions of support for requests to different versions of our backend service. I do not see a way to accomplish this. Do I need to create an entirely new Actions on Google project that has its own URL for fulfillment or is there some better way to accomplish this task?

I tried creating manually creating a separate Firebase project to host the Alpha code but that did not work. I later learned that when you create a Actions on Google project that it is intimately connected to the Firebase project created for it and cannot be pointed to another.

The problem is all in the configuration space of Actions on Google and Firebase. There is no code to show.

I would expect that some approach similar to that provided by the Alexa Developer Console and the Amazon Lambda Management Console would be available. In that approach, I have Alpha, Beta, and Production versions of the Alexa Skill and each of them points to a different version of the lambda function each of which has an appropriate value to indicate the environment that the lambda function is executing upon. This allows me to allocate requests to the correct backend service (alpha, beta, production).

I don't see a way to accomplish that in the Actions on Google/Firebase world.

Comment: Hey Jerome, have you got a way to do this? I am also looking for same information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Dialogflow, the Actions on Google release levels have corresponding [environments](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-versions). So you should be able to set a different fulfillment URL for each environment to point at the different project.