# How does version control work for actions on google?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have read the official article and it says that dialogflow automatically saves a snapshot of the agent when we release the action into a particular channel like Alpha , Beta or Production.
I have submitted my action for Production and it is under review. 
If I make any changes to my action now on the inline editor of dialogflow , they won't be reflected on the 
released version would they ? 
I am unsure due to the fact that it doesn't say deployed to any channel but says it's under review. Do I have to wait till it's in production ? There is no way to confirm that version control is in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make changes to either your webhook fulfillment *or* to the code in the Inline Editor, it goes into effect *immediately*. There is no version control at all for fulfillment.

At the same time, it means that if you make a change to fulfillment, you do not need to have it re-reviewed before it goes live.

The Alpha, Beta, and Production channels refer to the Intents, phrases, etc.

While, in theory, you can create a different environment for Alpha, Beta, and Production and in each environment use a different URL for the webhook, this definitely won't work if you're using the Inline Editor.

The best solution is to create a completely separate project and do your development and testing in that project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Then what should I do if I need to test some changes to the webhook fulfillment without having it released? Will I have to just make a copy of my current project ? It will be very helpful if you know the answer to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54262379/how-can-i-provide-different-fulfillment-urls-for-actions-on-google-release

Comment: Updated answer. If an answer helps, upvoting and/or accepting it are always appreciated.

Comment: So if I deploy my webhook fulfillment from a different source , how do I create a different environment and use a different webhook URL for each release ?